# How to use value of Wordpress custom plugin options in facebook pixel javascript code

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, facebook, woocommerce

I am creating a Facebook pixel plugin and I need to use pixel ID value using the WordPress plugin option define in my plugin.

Here is the option page

[image]

and this is my code

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'dvs_facebook_pixel_viewcontent' );
function dvs_facebook_pixel_viewcontent() { ?>
    <!-- Facebook Pixel Code -->
    <script>
    !function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s)
    {if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
    n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};
    if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';
    n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
    t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window, document,'script',
    'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');
    fbq('init', 'get_option('dvs_facebook_pixel');');
    fbq('track', 'PageView');
    fbq('track', 'ViewContent');
    </script>
    <noscript><img height="1" width="1" style="display:none"
    src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=823300961565807&ev=PageView&noscript=1"
    /></noscript>
    <!-- End Facebook Pixel Code -->
<?php }
```

I am adding

```
get_option('dvs_facebook_pixel');
in facebook script
fbq('init', 'get_option('dvs_facebook_pixel');');
```

but it is not working. What I am doing wrong?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the facebook script, Try echoing the option:

```
fbq('init', "<?php echo get_option('dvs_facebook_pixel');?>");
```

Comment: Thank you, there is also another code like  <noscript><img height="1" width="1" style="display:none"
 src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=<?php echo get_option('dvs_facebook_pixel');?>&ev=PageView&noscript=1"
 /></noscript> but is not working here.

Comment: What is the output look like?